# Drawing a Bar Chart with Plotly in R

Tags: r, plotly

I have one data frame (matrix 13x11).You can see pic below 
[image]

There are also data :

```
 # Data

        test_data_set<-structure(list(Name = c("Cars_sale_1", "Cars_sale_2", "Cars_sale_3", 
        "Cars_sale_4", "Cars_sale_5", "Cars_sale_6", "Cars_sale_7", "Cars_sale_8", 
        "Cars_sale_9", "Cars_sale_10", "Cars_sale_11", "Cars_sale_12", 
        "Cars_sale_13"), First = c(156300.824706096, 10006.2467099491, 
        3212.0722933848, 3319.03842779435, 9658.39620986138, 8434.32181084401, 
        1367.81891559923, 717.880329882435, 260.817687313564, 196.525706264257, 
        1042.98999824531, 7036.46253728724, 14974.7002155131), Second = c(227324.372696964, 
        16086.4713107563, 6318.58220740481, 21832.8829619231, 15740.5860677312, 
        10538.8313739252, 4399.92981224776, 2872.64432356554, 1391.68275135989, 
        0, 1979.57536409896, 12618.0733462011, 20694.7337436906), Third = c(277421.301982804, 
        18264.5376381821, 10922.6180031584, 30805.9659589402, 23327.3205825583, 
        14162.2038954203, 9179.99649061239, 5272.22319705212, 3019.19635023688, 
        0, 3587.71714335848, 17227.7241621337, 21867.2276106995), Fourth = c(307141.042288121, 
        27274.1182663625, 15141.1826636252, 51266.257238112, 25035.1289699947, 
        18876.8555886998, 13549.8859449026, 12045.9027899632, 4577.92595192139, 
        0, 9101.66695911564, 19369.2928583962, 30971.5263285415), Fifth = c(345904.895595719, 
        35406.3519915775, 21022.9163011055, 70233.5146516933, 28311.4932444288, 
        22832.3565537814, 21108.8261098438, 14801.7546938059, 4776.69766625724, 
        56.1502017897877, 11680.6457273206, 24203.544481488, 25989.4022630561
        ), Sixth = c(375676.013335673, 38199.2630286015, 34954.3428671697, 
        96511.528338305, 33332.4442884717, 27694.4025267591, 27706.1940691349, 
        26899.0349184067, 8709.73855062292, 224.600807159151, 16098.5436041411, 
        31910.4404281453, 32467.4847713049), Seventh = c(433176.346727496, 
        47455.623793648, 51832.251272153, 121340.024565713, 41695.1745920337, 
        31331.5318476926, 44969.8543604141, 24795.9291103702, 10157.0100017547, 
        828.215476399368, 27548.4120021056, 41680.0140375504, 35955.6910763933
        ), Eight = c(501520.687839972, 55052.4653447973, 74202.4916652044, 
        162651.693279523, 45550.4474469205, 40385.1903842779, 54554.132303913, 
        43609.6157220565, 16360.2035444815, 4171.95999298123, 45789.3665555361, 
        53713.5637831198, 29226.7897579876), Ninth = c(567436.251974031, 
        65858.0101772241, 104945.288647131, 238514.82716266, 60495.6659062993, 
        52381.4002456571, 100849.973679593, 61956.6941568696, 27927.4258641867, 
        4159.60694858747, 77211.5809791192, 69056.0449201614, 29472.1253015506
        ), Tenth = c(755730.057904896, 89047.2012633796, 208602.210914195, 
        544052.500438673, 195334.760484295, 129515.213195297, 220957.50131602, 
        119074.083172486, 115559.080540446, 36932.7952272328, 156449.622740832, 
        120385.751886296, 33197.0639513509)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = c("tbl_df", 
        "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My intention is to make two graph bar plots in R like pics below with package Plotly, which are drawn in Excel.

[image]
[image]

How do you draw a stacked bar plot with the `Plotly` package in R?

Comment: Please include your attempt(s) :)!

Comment: My attemps is based on this page https://plot.ly/r/bar-charts/#stacked-bar-chart, but unfortunately I do not get roughly anything like the way I want it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your rows and columns have to be exchanged. Once it is done, you have to factor the order of First, Second etc in order for them to be printed in the right order

```
library(plotly)
t_df <- data.frame(t(test_data_set[,-1]))
colnames(t_df) <- test_data_set$Name
t_df$Number <- factor(row.names(t_df),levels=row.names(t_df),ordered=TRUE)

p <- plot_ly(t_df, x = ~Number, y = ~Cars_sale_1, type = 'bar', name = 'Cars_sale_1') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_2, name = 'Cars_sale_2') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_3, name = 'Cars_sale_3') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_4, name = 'Cars_sale_4') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_5, name = 'Cars_sale_5') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_6, name = 'Cars_sale_6') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_7, name = 'Cars_sale_7') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_8, name = 'Cars_sale_8') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_9, name = 'Cars_sale_9') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_10, name = 'Cars_sale_10') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_11, name = 'Cars_sale_11') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_12, name = 'Cars_sale_12') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_13, name = 'Cars_sale_13') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Count'), barmode = 'stack')
p
```

[image]
For the second graph I created a new dataframe where I make sure that every row has sum 1

```
t_df_pct <- t_df
t_df_pct[,1:(ncol(t_df)-1)] <- t_df_pct[,1:(ncol(t_df)-1)]/rowSums(t_df_pct[,1:(ncol(t_df)-1)])

p2 <- plot_ly(t_df_pct, x = ~Number, y = ~Cars_sale_1, type = 'bar', name = 'Cars_sale_1') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_2, name = 'Cars_sale_2') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_3, name = 'Cars_sale_2') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_4, name = 'Cars_sale_4') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_5, name = 'Cars_sale_5') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_6, name = 'Cars_sale_6') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_7, name = 'Cars_sale_7') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_8, name = 'Cars_sale_8') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_9, name = 'Cars_sale_9') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_10, name = 'Cars_sale_10') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_11, name = 'Cars_sale_11') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_12, name = 'Cars_sale_12') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~Cars_sale_13, name = 'Cars_sale_13') %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = 'Percentage'), barmode = 'stack')
p2
```

[image: second barplot]